# Automatically return derivative from ode solver at each solution point in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

The standard Matlab ode45 call is:

```
[T,Y] = solver(odefun,tspan,y0,options);
```

But I also want the value of `odefun`at each state vector `Y`. It seems like there should be an option to return something like

```
[T,Y, DYDT] = solver(odefun,tspan,y0,options);
```

as this would be the most efficient way, since the routine already evaluates the derivative at each point internally. The obvious work around is to do

```
DYDT = odefun(T,Y);
```

however then I would need to write a modified version of `odefun` since the one you pass to the `solver` should be a column vector denoting a single state. Here obviously I am wanting to calculate `DYDT` at all states `Y` returned by the `solver`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is away to get the derivative directly.

May be you could try something like:

```
tspan = 0:0.001:5; % choose a time-interval
x0 = 5 % and an initial condition
```

run you `ode45` code

```
[~,xt_solution]=ode45('odefun',tspan,x0);
```

and then diffenrentiate your solution:

```
tdiff=diff(tspan);
xdiff=diff(xt_solution);
dxdt=xdiff1./tdiff1;
```

And there you go. You will have the values of the derivative together with its corresponding `tspan` value! Just remember that your ´dxdt´ array will have one element less than `xt_solution`. This is because of the way we are differentiating `xt_solution`

If you must have both arrays of the same `dim` you can go:

```
if size(xt_solution,1) > size(dxdt,1)
    xt_solution = xt_solution(1:size(dxdt,1),:);
end
```

So the trick is to predefine your `tspan` from before and then use it to find the derivative!

Comment: Hmm- I'm not sure I want to use finite differences when I can calculate the derivative exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you write your `odefun` to cope both with scalars and vectors (for example using `.*`), you should be able to do what you suggest (`dydt = odefun(t,y);`). Other than that, you can use a for loop to go through the time vector returned by the `ode` solver (maybe not very efficient, but pretty robust).

I don't think there is a way to have the `ode` solver return the derivative along with the solution.